# Responsive pyramid from divs elements

Tags: css

I need create responsive pyramid from div elements. Each element of pyramid (triangle on top and next quadrilaterals under him) must be divs, because I need every element of pyramid like clickable link. I am new in css and I am grateful for every help.

Like Below Image: [image]

Comment: Please provide us more details, as what you have tried, what are the result, where are you stuck. Posting your code or fiddle would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine strange answer to the strange question .

```css
.pi {
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 200px 500px;
}
.pi div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.cont {
  perspective: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class=cont>
  <div class=pi>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. It's not responsive 2. the heights are messed up due to perspective.

Answer (score -2):

Hello the result in the given link can be produced by using pseudo element in each div for making triangle and quadrilaterals. Refer to the below two link for your problem.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Low quality answer to a low quality question

Comment: Thanks, but my problem ist, that pyramid must be responsible and i dont know how find size of triangle down side to set size of top quadrilateral side under triangle.